# List all databases by elastic pool using T-Sql in Azure Sql

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-elasticpool

There is a need that I need to create a query (T-Sql) where I will list the databases (name) given the elastic pool name. However, I couldn't find a sys.stats*** table or view that will give me this information , the simplest query I want to run is below but it could be any complex query as far as it gives me the list of dbs in an elastic pool

`SELECT databaseName  from sometable where elasticpoolname ='pool-1'`

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I was able to manage list all dbs in a pool thru

```
SELECT
       @@SERVERNAME as [ServerName],
       dso.elastic_pool_name,
       d.name as DatabaseName,
       dso.edition
FROM
       sys.databases d inner join sys.database_service_objectives dso on d.database_id = dso.database_id
WHERE d.Name <> 'master'
ORDER BY
       d.name, dso.elastic_pool_name
```